# Bootstrap - One Background Image for two divs

Tags: html, css, background, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m a CSS beginner. I´ve got two separate containers which should have one background image. I'm using z-index but I don´t know how to make it work.

```
<!-- Background Image -->
<div class="bg-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bg/bgtriangle.png">

<!-- First Container -->
 <div class="container-main">
  <p class="font-relative">Headline 1</p>                      
 </div> 

<!-- Second Container -->
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #574c5d; border-top: 2px solid     #e57e22;"> 
  <h4 class="text-center" style="padding: 5px;">Headline 2</h4>
 </div>

</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.container-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: #453a4b;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;      
}   

.bg-img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

How can I use this one bg-image in full width for two containers? Is that possible?

Comment: So let me understand this right, you want the bg-img to stretch through container main and container fluid?

Comment: You should use a background image with CSS background-image instead of a HTML img element.

Comment: Yes that the idea, I would like it to stretch through both container. Each container has a background-color and I would like to have the image on top of the color but below the content. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your image to the `background-image` of your `bg-img` instead of adding it as an HTML `img` element. Also, you do not need z-index at all for this - they can be removed from your CSS.

```
.bg-img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('images/bg/bgtriangle.png'); /* This */
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to move the background of the divs behind the background image, while keeping the content above it, you are going to get into a bit of a messy situation. You can do this by removing the contents from the divs, and then positioning all of them as absolute and using z-index (-1 behind image and 1 in-front of image). However, this means that you have to use top/left/etc. to position the contents back into their divs.

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kto126y7/3/)** of what I accomplished tinkering a bit, maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thx for your help! Is there a way how I could put the image above the backgroundcolor of the two containers but still below the content of each container?

Comment: @madlm I updated my answer. Be warned that to do what you are asking, positioning your elements is going to be a bit messy.

Comment: but the background-image still stays behind the background-coler of the two divs?

Comment: @madlm Did you look at my updated demo? The background color of the divs are both behind the background image, while the content is in front.

Comment: sorry if did explain myself right. I´m triend to get the Background-image on top of the background-color of the two divs but underneath the text

Comment: @madlm Could you please explain how my demo differs from what you are asking for? In my demo, the background image (Google) is above the background colors of the div (one red and one gray), but underneath of the text (Headline 1 and Headline 2). Unless I am misunderstanding, I have done what I believe you are asking.

Comment: Sry, I made en example of what i´m trying to do: 

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=fbe1c8-1409170890.jpg

the picture at the top is what i see in the demo, the bottom image is what i´m trying to do. Putting one image visibly above the background of two divs but below their content